# Sticking a UIView to the bottom of a UICollectionView that works in 3.5 and 4 inches

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am trying to stick a UIView, containing an ADBannerView, to the bottom of my UICollectionView that works in both 3.5 and 4". My current implementation works for 4" but it gets cut off in 3.5".

**3.5"**

[image]

**4"**

[image]

**Storyboard**

[image]
[image]

**Constraints**

[image]

My constraints are essentially setup as: height = 50, space to the left, right and bottom of the screen = 0. As a test, I tried the same constraints on a separate UIViewController and it works as expected. The same constraints doesn't seem to be working in an UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `collectionView` has leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints of 0 to its superview, which will ensure that the `collectionView` always occupies and is contained by the full screen.

You can then add leading/trailing/bottom constraints of 0 and height of 50 to the `bannerView` with respect to its superview (the `collectionView`). And because the `collectionView` will be constrained to always be fullscreen, without bleeding off, you know that the `bannerView` will always occupy the bottom 50 pixels of the screen too.

OR

You can add leading/trailing/bottom constraints of 0 and height of 50 to the `bannerView` with respect to its superview (the `viewController` (NOT the `collectionView`)) so that it really has nothing to do with the `collectionView`, instead it's just pinned to the bottom of the encompassing view.

Two approaches that should yield the same result.

Hope this helps!

**Update**

Adding an observation from my comment below:

I also now am noticing that your bannerView is a subview of a cell. This is probably not what you intend, right? (ie you dont want a banner for every cell). It should probably be a subview of the collectionView, or better yet the encompassing UIViewController...

Comment: 1) How do you set the contraints for collectionView? There isn't a superview for it? 2) My `DetailViewController` is a `UICollectionViewController` so there isnt a regular view controller. Should I embed my collection view in a normal view controller you think?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I missed that detail. I also now am noticing that your bannerView is a subview of a cell. This is probably not what you intend, right? It should be a subview of the collectionView...